# "IndexError: tuple index out of range" on train_test_split train data once attempting to fit for preprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I was trying to pre-process my data using normalization.

```
# preprocessing
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)
btc_data = pd.read_csv(
    "output.csv",
    names=["Time", "Open"])

ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["Time", "Open"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["Time", "Open"])
)

X_btc = btc_data["Time"]
y_btc = btc_data["Open"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_btc, y_btc, test_size=0.2, random_state=62)

ct.fit(X_train)
X_train_normal = ct.transform(X_train)
X_test_normal = ct.transform(X_test)
```

The code runs on a Colab notebook. The dataset is from Kaple and it is modified to be full of Unix Timestamps and another column for prices of Bitcoin on open at those times. After spliting the data and creating a column transformer, I tried fitting the data. However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-f73622372111> in <module>()
     27 print(X_train.shape)
     28 
---> 29 ct.fit(X_train)
     30 X_train_normal = ct.transform(X_train)
     31 X_test_normal = ct.transform(X_test)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in _get_column_indices(X, key)
    387     :func:`_safe_indexing_column`.
    388     """
--> 389     n_columns = X.shape[1]
    390 
    391     key_dtype = _determine_key_type(key)

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I am wondering if it is a shape issue, but as a note, the X_train data is of shape `(2020896,)`.

Is there something I have to do with my data to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extracted the X_btc  as a Pandas Series which is like 1D array, you need to extract DataFrame (2D array/matrix). Replace:

```
X_btc = btc_data["Time"]
```

with:

```
X_btc = btc_data[["Time"]]
```

to extract the DataFrame

#### Edit for the new error:

KeyError happens because this transformer:

```
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["Time", "Open"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["Time", "Open"])
)
```

You are using `["Time", "Open"]` columns. However, the X_btc has no column `"Open"`  (as you selected only column `"Time"`). The `"Open"` is the target label (`y_btc`) and you should not include it into `X_btc`. In that case, you can remove `"Open"` from `make_column_transformer`:

```
ct = make_column_transformer(
    (MinMaxScaler(), ["Time"]),
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), ["Time"])
)
```

Comment: That did change it into a 2D array but it caused a different error: https://pastebin.com/dVRqu7ir

Comment: See the edit in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Please clarify @KhosrawAzizi , what do you try to achieve with this column transformer? OneHotEncode (OHE) is for categorical data, and as I understand the Time contains timestamps, and Open contains prices. Both variables are continuous, but OHE is designed to work with categorical data. MinMaxScaler is somewhat fine, as it works with continuous variables. However, I doubt it should be used for timestamps and prices.

Another thing is the problem formulation. Do you want to predict the price based on the timestamp? Do you want to forecast future prices?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm learning my way through TensorFlow for a Science Fair project. Since right now I am playing through Linear Regression, I wanted to try to use normalization to convert my data between 0s and 1s. I understand that I probably won't need to OneHotEncode since my data doesn't contain any String data. I will probably be removing that later. For right now, I am trying to decrease my run-time and loss by normalizing, because I plan on training the model to predict future prices and then confirming them given newly available data from Yahoo Finance's API.

Comment: For right now, I'm trying to figure out how to convert my X_train_normal to an array using numpy, but my run-time is using a lot of memory when trying to convert it. Will end up having to open another question for that one if I can't figure out a way around it.

Comment: Update: Removing OneHotEncode from the Column Transformer fixed that issue as well.

Comment: EDIT: I submitted the response 40 seconds after your update :) Your runtime is using lots of memory because of OHE (presumably). What is the shape reported by running `X_train_normal.shape`? If it has a large number in the second place then it should be OHE's fault. Other than that, the column transformer `transform` method returns NumPy array (or sparse SciPy matrix), but not DataFrame

Comment: Yes, I went back and checked and it was very much literally out of shape. I don't have to convert `X_train_normal` at all.